# How do I select from a given set of values, rounding up?

Tags: ruby, math, hashtable

I've got a ruby array of hashes with two keys, 'tier' and 'price'. For a given price, I want to return the tier.

This is simple enough with exact matching, but how do I ensure I *always* have a match by rounding my input value up to the next value in the array?

For example, given the array below, if I have a value of '499', I want to return '10'.

```
tiers = [
    { tier: 0, price: 0 },
    { tier: 1, price: 50 },
    { tier: 2, price: 100 },
    { tier: 3, price: 150 },
    { tier: 4, price: 200 },
    { tier: 5, price: 250 },
    { tier: 6, price: 300 },
    { tier: 7, price: 350 },
    { tier: 8, price: 400 },
    { tier: 9, price: 450 },
    { tier: 10, price: 500 },
    { tier: 11, price: 550 },
    { tier: 12, price: 600 },
    { tier: 13, price: 650 },
    { tier: 14, price: 700 },
    { tier: 15, price: 750 },
    { tier: 16, price: 800 },
    { tier: 17, price: 850 },
    { tier: 18, price: 880 },
    { tier: 19, price: 950 },
    { tier: 20, price: 1000 }
]
```

I can get an exact match with `tiers.detect { |tier| tier[:price] == "500"}[:tier]`, but this will return an error if I don't have a match. I could increment my input value until I return a match but that seems very inefficient.

I considered rounding my input value, but you'll notice that the increment isn't always the same (from tier 17 to 18 the price only increases by 30).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could enumerate all tiers in pairs and evaluate your price against the pair. Something like this:

```
def detect_tier(price)
  tiers.each_cons(2) do |t1, t2|
    next if price < t1[:price] # too low
    next if price > t2[:price] # too high

    return t1[:tier] if price == t1[:price] # matches tier price exactly
    return t2[:tier] # "round up"
  end
end

detect_tier(10) # => 1
detect_tier(100) # => 2
detect_tier(499) # => 10
```

Comment: Yep, this is doing the trick. I'm still trying to grok the logic here but it certainly seems to be exactly what I was after!

Comment: @NickBarreto: read documentation on `each_cons`, it's the core of the solution here

Comment: Yep, that's really useful. Thanks! @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 1):

If the array is large it would be prudent to use the *find-minimum mode*
 of the method [Array#bsearch_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index), which would reduce the time complexity from O(n) with a sequential search to O(log n).

I have assumed the values of `:price` in `tiers` are increasing and that `nil` is to be returned if the test price exceeds `tiers.last[:price]`.

```
def round_up(tiers, price)
  return nil if price > tiers.last[:price]
  tiers[tiers.map { |h| h[:price] }.bsearch_index { |p| p >= price }][:tier]
end
```

Let's try it.

```
tiers = [
  { tier: "cat", price:   0 },
  { tier: "dog", price:  50 },
  { tier: "pig", price: 100 },
  { tier: "owl", price: 150 },
  { tier: "ram", price: 300 }
]

round_up(tiers, -10) #=> "cat"
round_up(tiers,   0) #=> "cat"
round_up(tiers,   1) #=> "dog"
round_up(tiers,  49) #=> "dog"
round_up(tiers,  50) #=> "dog"
round_up(tiers,  51) #=> "pig"
round_up(tiers, 150) #=> "owl"
round_up(tiers, 250) #=> "ram"
round_up(tiers, 300) #=> "ram"
round_up(tiers, 301) #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tiers.detect{|x| x[:price] >= <required_number>}[:tier]
```

could work, if the tiers are structured as given.

Doesn't handle the boundary conditions though.

```
tiers.detect{|x| x[:price] >= 1}[:tier] #=> 1
tiers.detect{|x| x[:price] >= 100}[:tier] #=> 2
tiers.detect{|x| x[:price] >= 499}[:tier] #=> 10
tiers.detect{|x| x[:price] >= 750}[:tier] #=> 15
```

Comment: use `detect` instead of `select.first`

Comment: Prakash, if you agree with @Sergio that `detect` (aka `find`) is preferred (I do), I suggest you revise your answer to remove the `select` answer. In general, you only weaken your answer by including less-desireable solutions. The fact that you did not initially use `detect` is irrelevant. Also, to keep your answer clean, if you wish to thank Sergio, I suggest you do that in a comment. I might have written something like this: "Thanks, Sergio, that's better. I did an edit.  Readers: I formerly wrote...".

Comment: @CarySwoveland: couldn't have said this better myself :)